# How to get the schema of an Apollo federation without running the whole code?

Tags: typegraphql, apollo-federation

I want to implement [operational and composition checks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/studio/schema-checks/) on my federated graph. To do this, I need either a schema file or I need to pipe the results of the graph introspection query into the rover command that does the check. I don't have a file describing the schema. As I understand it, the schema is only generated from the code when the server starts up. The introspection approach works but it makes no sense when I move this process to my CI/CD pipeline. I don't want to be spinning up the gateway + all the microservices just so that I can run a introspection. Is there a way to generate a schema without spinning up all these processes? I'm using type-graphql and I know it can emit schemas for "normal" graphs like [this](https://typegraphql.com/docs/emit-schema.html#:%7E:text=To%20accomplish%20this%20demand%2C%20TypeGraphQL,of%20the%20project%27s%20working%20directory.) but I don't know how to do the same for a federated schema.

In effect, I need a more lightweight way to run something like `rover graph introspect http://localhost:3000 | rover graph check {{my-gateway}}@develop --schema -`

Answer (score 0):

Running a schema check on your gateway will always fail by design, the best approach for this is to run a schema check on your subgraphs. [Using introspection is strongly advised against in a production environment](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/security/why-you-should-disable-graphql-introspection-in-production/#what-is-it). Details on federated graph composition can be found in the [Apollo docs here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federated-types/composition), as well as for [managed federation schema checks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/managed-federation/federated-schema-checks).